# Android close activities on StatusBarNotification pressed

Tags: android, android-activity

In my application I'm using some activities that can run each other. On resume of every activity I'm checking current application state, and if it changed, I run appropriate activity.

When user is not in application, he retrieves status bar notifications, and when he presses on it, an appropriate activity opens.

But when user goes to home screen from application, the last application activity saved to backStack, and when application state changes and status bar notifications is sent, user by click opens appropriate activity. But when user presses Back button, the previous application activity is restored.

So I want to have only one activity running even with status bar notifications. How can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add this `android:noHistory="true"` in your activity tag inside the `manifest` file.

Answer (score 0):

try this.

```
Intent notifyIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
notifyIntent.setClass(getApplicationContext(), Main.class);
```